# Comparing two Dates in Excel using TEXT function. Exceptional behaviour on certain dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am trying to compare two dates in Excel using the following formula:

```
=IF(TEXT(B1,"dd-mmm-yyyy")>"15-Jun-2019","New","Old")
```

wherein I want the dates after June 15, 2019 are tagged as "New", while the others are tagged as "Old.
B1 contains a date, such as `09-Oct-2018` in the "Date" format in Excel (dd-mmm-yyyy).

The formula usually seems to be working fine, with some exceptions.

When the date is particularly between `15-Oct-18` and `31-Oct-18`, the formula returns a "New", wherein logically it should return an "Old". (Please check attached screenshot).

Although I was able to achieve this using the `DATEVALUE`, or `NUMBERVALUE` functions and then the comparison seems to be working fine; but I am not able to understand this unusual behaviour using the TEXT function.

Reference Screenshot of Excel:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but sadly, it doesn't really explain the comparison. If this had to be the case, then 11-Oct-18 and 15-Oct-18 should have given same result on comparison with 15-Jun-2019.

Comment: "15-Oct-18" returns "New" because "O" is after "J" in alphabet. Why do you think that 11-Oct-18 should give the same result as 15-Oct-18 when you compare it with 15-Jun-2019 as text?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is worth revisiting a couple of core concepts in Excel.

(1) Character strings are compared character by character as mentioned in the link by @barbsan [String comparison using inequalities in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785909/string-comparison-using-inequalities-in-excel). It is like looking up a word in an English dictionary (or any other language), so "ABCD"<"ABCE" and "ABC"<"ABCD", except that any digits and special characters in a string are treated the same way as letters and have their own code used for comparison and sorting (although "abc" may or may not be equal to "ABC" depending on context).

(2) All data items in Excel may be stored either as character strings or numbers. But numbers may be formatted to look like currency, time, fractions or in this case dates. The formatting doesn't change the value that's been stored.

[image]

Comment: That point (2) is so important and I feel many new comers miss that important nuance!

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the dates to text hence excel will compare text pattern as in English dictionary. Your inputs are not treated as dates if you use text. I will suggest not to use text in your formula directly use the dates for comparision and you will get the desired results. If you have any other condition please post.