# How to modify GetMaxString code for GetMinString?

Tags: vba

```
Public Function GetMaxString(ByRef strValues() As String) As String
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(strValues) To UBound(strValues)
    If GetMaxString < strValues(i) Then GetMaxString = strValues(i)
Next i
End Function
```

I'm a novice that tried to simply change
"If GetMaxString < strValues(i)" to "If GetMaxString > strValues(i)" but that didn't work

Comment: Is your modified function still named `GetMaxString` ?  It would be useful to edit your question to add the code for your modified function, and maybe explain a bit more what you mean by "didn't work" (how was the outcome different from what you expected?)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785909/string-comparison-using-inequalities-in-excel

Comment: Are the strings numeric? VBA does some auto-conversions for you when you attempt to compare non-numeric values using numeric operators like `<` and `>`. But this will run into an error if the string isn't able to be auto-converted.To avoid errors and to make the code more robust, I suggest adding explicit checks `If IsNumeric(strValues(i)) Then` and an explicit conversion in the comparison `GetMaxString < CDbl(strValues(i))`

Answer (score 0):

The GetMaxString will work, provided the given values adheres to all the basic rules, such as NOT empty, at least two strings to allow comparison. But any of the presumptions not met means the function will break down.

So the GetMinString should avoid having the same assumptions as the GetMaxString.

```
Public Function GetMinString(ByRef strValues() As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer, max As Integer
    
    max = UBound(strValues) - LBound(strValues) + 1
    If max > 1 Then
        GetMinString = strValues(LBound(strValues))
        For i = LBound(strValues) + 1 To UBound(strValues)
            If GetMinString > strValues(i) Then GetMinString = strValues(i)
        Next i
    ElseIf max = 1 Then
        GetMinString = strValues(1)
    Else
        GetMinString = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Try to understand the GetMinString logic then you can use it to improve your GetMaxString.

You can use the following function to test that the above works

```
Public Sub testfunction()
    Dim tts(2) As String
    tts(0) = "5"
    tts(1) = "2"
    tts(2) = "1"
    Debug.Print "[" & GetMinString(tts) & "]"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the above solution.  There are times when there is only a single string, so I change the strValue index to (0) for case when Max = 1
ElseIf max = 1 Then  GetMinString = strValues(1)          changed to strValues(0)

Comment: The excel cells are using the workday function which calls a UDF for the start date entry.
The UDF that calls the GetMinString is as follows:
Public Function MinPreds(Preds) As String
    Dim Rng As String
    Dim TempRng As String
    Dim PredsArray() As String
    Dim MinDate As Variant
    TempRng = Replace(Preds, " ", "")
    Rng = UCase(TempRng)
    PredsArray = Split(Rng, ",")
    MinDate = GetMinString(PredsArray)
    MinPreds = Range(MinDate)
End Function